# Using the same session in applications under the same server and domain IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, session-state

There are two applications under one domain.

```
example.com
example.com/module1
example.com/module2
```

If there is no module1 and module2 session, go to example.com. User must login to example.com. User can use that session in module1 and module2 after login.

How do I do this? Can I use session state for that?

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" cookieless="false" />
```

Comment: "How do I do this?" and "Can I use session state for that?" cover a large scope; you need to narrow/clarify the focus of your question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

To share session states among multiple applications you need to specify the same sharedId in web.config(sessionState element) for both applications.

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
  <providers>
    <!-- specify the named cache for session data -->
    <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" 
         type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider" 
         cacheName="NamedCache1"
         sharedId="SharedApp"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

More information you can refer to this link: [Configuring an ASP.NET Session State Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/appfabric/ee790859(v=azure.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).